# Safe wallet targeting alternative bundlers / paymasters?

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk, erc-4337, paymaster

In July the Safe team [announced](https://safe.mirror.xyz/rjWPvQjH9XEC2bADp-9Q1ZEW675pMu41hWsoX5v0Ros)

> Previously, developers building on Safe{Core} were able to build on the Relay Kit using technology from Gelato. With ERC-4337 integrations supported in v.1.4.1, developers now have further flexibility to choose the preferred relayer technologies that they want to build with, or to build their own relay modules.

Are there any examples out there of not using [Gelato](https://www.gelato.network) with Safe?

From what I can see Gelato integration is via a [Relay pack](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/blob/main/packages/relay-kit/src/packs/gelato/GelatoRelayPack.ts). From a glance this api does not seem fully aligned with 4337 even though it's in their Account Abstraction SDK.

My desire is to hot-swap bundlers if a provider goes down.